# Python Networkx and Pandas library not working

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv, networkx

My code below is supposed to print a graph/network using **Networkx**, **Pandas** and data from a CSV file. The code is (networkx3.py) -

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

g = nx.Graph()
csv_dict = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', index_col=[0])
csv_1 = csv_dict.values.tolist()

ini = 0
for row in csv_1:
    for i in row:
        if type(row[i]) is str:
            g.add_edge(ini, int(i), conn_prob=(float(row[i])))

    max_wg_ngs = sorted(g[ini].items(), key=lambda e: e[1]["conn_prob"], reverse=True)[:2]
    sarr = [str(a) for a in max_wg_ngs]
    print "Neighbours of Node %d are:" % ini       
    #print(max_wg_ngs)
    for item in sarr:
        print ''.join(str(item))[1:-1]

    ini += 1

pos = nx.spring_layout(g, scale=100.)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos)
#plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The data in the CSV file is (Book1.csv) -

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,0,0.257905291,0.775104118,0.239086843,0.002313744,0.416936603,0.194817214,0.163350301,0.252043807,0.251272559
2,0.346100279,0,0.438892758,0.598885794,0.002263231,0.406685237,0.523850975,0.257660167,0.206302228,0.161385794
3,0.753358102,0.222349243,0,0.407830809,0.001714776,0.507573592,0.169905687,0.139611318,0.187910832,0.326950557
4,0.185342928,0.571302688,0.51784403,0,0.003231018,0.295197533,0.216184462,0.153032751,0.216331326,0.317961522
5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
6,0.478164621,0.418192795,0.646810223,0.410746629,0.002414973,0,0.609176897,0.203461461,0.157576977,0.636747837
7,0.24894327,0.522914349,0.33948832,0.316240267,0.002335929,0.639377086,0,0.410011123,0.540266963,0.587764182
8,0.234017887,0.320967208,0.285193773,0.258198079,0.003146737,0.224412057,0.411725737,0,0.487081815,0.469526333
9,0.302955306,0.080506624,0.261610132,0.22856311,0.001746979,0.014994905,0.63386228,0.486096957,0,0.664434415
10,0.232675407,0.121596312,0.457715027,0.310618067,0.001872929,0.57556548,0.473562887,0.32185564,0.482351246,0
```

The code however doesn't work. I don't understand where I'm going wrong. The error is -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "networkx3.py", line 13, in <module>
    if type(row[i]) is str:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

I do not want to modify the CSV file or its data. The index column and header are supposed to be ignored.
I have previously asked this question but I did not get satisfactory answers. Can anybody help?
Thanks a lot in advance :) (Using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit VM. Credits to @Adonis for helping in creating the original code)

Comment: You have `for i in row`.  The first time through that loop, what do you think the value of `i` is?  Perhaps try printing it to be sure.  The next question is why do you expect `row[i]` to be meaningful on the next line - what are you assuming the value of `i` is in that statement?  Hint - the error message is telling you that the list index is not an integer.  What is the only thing being used like a list index in that statement?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Joel . I am actually new to Python, hence I do not know a great deal. I did not understand the hint you gave earlier. But I tried printing `i` and they're the values are from the CSV file.

Comment: So hopefully you've realized that `i` is what you expected `row[i]` to be.

Comment: @Joel that's right. But I'm still stuck with the code, unable to move forward :( . Any more suggestions you could give? I really appreciate your help

Comment: so you shouldn't be doing anything with `row[i]`.  Everywhere you have `row[i]` you almost certainly mean `i`.  [and `i` is a poor choice for the name for the entry -  you should use a more descriptive name]

Comment: @Joel I finally have the answer. Thanks again for the guidance :)

Comment: Good.  Please take some time to make sure you understand why what you were doing was an error.  Otherwise, you'll end up repeating something similar in the future and it'll again take a while to get things fixed.  Make sure you read about how for loops work in Python, for example read https://stackoverflow.com/a/4171389/2966723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late in answering my own question, but with some valuable help from @Joel and @Adonis, I finally figured out where I was going wrong.
The problem was in the 2nd `for` loop where I tried to pass a `float` value as a `string` into the Graph which gave me an error. Other minor changes would result in an output but without any edges, just nodes.
Finally, after using an `enumerate` function to define a connecting node (using its index giving power), I got the required output. The only changes to be made are in the 2nd `for` loop and the `if` condition:
    `for row in csv_1:
        for idx, i in enumerate(row):
            if type(row[idx]) is float:
                g.add_edge(ini, idx, conn_prob=(float(row[idx])))`

Thanks to all the selfless guys at SOF for the help, couldn't have done it without you :)