# finding sum using for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, sum

when we have to add in python via for loops then we have to type something like this:

```
>>> list(range(1,10))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> total=0
... for element in range(1,10) :
...     total+=element
>>> print(total)
45
```

But i tried doing something else, i did not defined total in the benign and later just defined total as (`total=element`). and when i print `total` then every time `4` is coming no matter which number sequence i have. Can any one explain the reason that why every time `4` is coming?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python)

Comment: That's because 4 is the last element in your list a

Comment: This is because print statement is not in that for loop but outside of that which is considering the last iteration of your loop and thus last value of the list `a`.

Comment: @roxaite Please do not post pictures of code and error messages, post the text directly here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need for loops for that?

```
print(sum(range(10))
```

The thing, you've said did not really work, because that's the way for loop works.
It replaced total with the element it used right now.

Answer (score 0):

You replaced `total += e` with `total = e`. So only the last value is used.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list `a = [1,2,3,4]` and total = 0
Then, you are iteration the list

```
for e in a:
    total = a
print (total)
```

In every iteration the value of `total` is replacing with `a` and at the last iteration the value of `a (= 4)` is replacing the previous value  of `total`.
That's why it's printing `4` every time.

If you want to get the total value just replace

```
total = a
```

with

```
total += a
```