# What is the inteded way to use foreach in Python?

Tags: python

I have a situation where I need to populate a list that is going to be a part of a larger data structure with a series of identical values. Now, in any other programming language I would do it for example like this (let itemIndexes be a list of item indexes):

```
targetStatusCode = "TC13"
statusCodes = []
foreach itemIndexes:
    statusCodes .append(targetStatusCode)
```

However, in Python, this is apparently not possible.

Instead, I have now settled for this:

```
targetStatusCode = "TC13"
statusCodes = []
for each in itemIndexes:
    statusCodes .append(targetStatusCode)
```

However, this results in me getting a warning "local variable 'each' is not used anymore".

So, here's my question: Is there an intended "ideal" way to handle this specific sort of situation in python that does not generate a warning?

---

Explanation why this is not a duplicate of [for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python)

I already tried the above solution, and it raises the IDE warning I described above. My question was for a "clean" solution that allows me to do this without my IDE raising a "variable is not used anymore"-warning. One of the answers below thankfully provided a working solution for this.

Comment: `statusCodes = [targetStatusCode] * len(itemIndexes)` ? no loops at all

Comment: Your question and it's description... It seems that you did not tried reading python documentation at all. Take a look at [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration) for instance

Comment: And anyway, whatever you used that threw the warning, it's just an information that something wrong **might** be going on and that you might have to give it a second look, nothing more. As a side note, it's a common convention in Python  to use `_` as variable name in such situations.

Comment: The supposed duplicate asks how to loop over integers with a step different from 1, which is unrelated to the question asked here - which luckily got useful answers before being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're adding strings specifically (more complex objects would run into issues with duplicated references), you could probably just use a list literal for this:

```
statusCodes = [targetStatusCode] * len(itemIndexes)
```

If you feel the need to use a `for` loop in particular, then you're doing it correctly - the IDE you're using probably shouldn't be yelling at you. But to make it *more clear* that you're using the `for` loop to iterate just a specific number of times, you can change what you call the loop control variable:

```
for _ in itemIndexes:
    statusCodes.append(targetStatusCode)
```

in which case, if your IDE or linter gives you a warning, you should look into its settings and see if you can disable that warning.

---

It also seems like you have a misconception about `for` loops in python. You imply that `foreach` loops don't exist in python, when, in fact, *all `for` loops* are `foreach` loops in python. The syntax is `for var in iterable:`, where `iterable` *must* be some object that can be iterated through (to iterate through the values 0 through 9, you use the `range(10)` function instead of the C-style `for (i=0; i < 10; i++)`)

Comment: Thank you very much, Green Cloak Guy! The `for _ in itemIndexes` works great and also doesn't raise a warning in my IDE. I don't want to disable these warnings because they are warnings that inform me of unused variables.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution, since all your 'terms' are the same, is to simply do:

```
statusCodes = ["TC13"] * len(itemIndexes)
```

However, if you wanted to iterate over the items and possibly use their values while constructing statusCodes, the most pythonic way is to use List Comprehension:

```
statusCodes = [ "TC13" for item in itemIndexes ]
```