# Generate number not in array

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

Hello I am doing the following programming exercise: [Squad number generator](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5d62961d18198b000e2f22b3). The statement is:

> At the start of each season, every player in a football team is
>   assigned their own unique squad number. Due to superstition or their
>   history certain numbers are more desirable than others.
>
> Write a function generateNumber() that takes two arguments, an array
>   of the current squad numbers (squad) and the new player's desired
>   number (n). If the new player's desired number is not already taken,
>   return n, else if the desired number can be formed by adding two
>   digits between 1 and 9, return the number formed by joining these two
>   digits together. E.g. If 2 is taken, return 11 because 1 + 1 = 2.
>   Otherwise return null.
>
> Note: Often there will be several different ways to form a replacement
>   number. In these cases the number with lowest first digit should be
>   given priority. E.g. If n = 15, but squad already contains 15, return
>   69, not 78.

We would like to learn how the following algorithm could be improved:

```
def generate_number(squad, n): #☘️
    print("squad: ",squad)
    print("n: ",n)
    if n not in squad: return n
    firstDigit = n%9
    secondDigit = 9
    squadNumber = int(str(firstDigit)+str(secondDigit))
    while squadNumber <= 99 and squadNumber in squad:
        print("squadNumber: ",squadNumber)
        firstDigit+=1
        secondDigit-=1
        while(firstDigit+secondDigit != n):
            print("inside squadNumber: ",squadNumber)
            firstDigit+=1
            secondDigit-=1
            squadNumber = int(str(firstDigit)+str(secondDigit))
        squadNumber = int(str(firstDigit)+str(secondDigit))
    return squadNumber if squadNumber <= 99 else None
```

The question would be: how do we get a two digits combination which summed are n?

For example:

```
n = 11 -> 11%9 = 2 -> 2+9 = 11 -> 29
n = 16 -> 16%9 = 7 -> 7+9 = 16 -> 79
n = 10 -> 10%9 = 1 -> 1+9 = 10 -> 19
```

However what would happen if n is 18 and it is currently being in the squad. The algorithm should return the next lowest, which would be 99...

But our code's trace would be:

```
squad:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15, 18, 23, 69]
n:  18
squadNumber:  9
inside squadNumber:  9
inside squadNumber:  27
inside squadNumber:  36
inside squadNumber:  45
inside squadNumber:  54
inside squadNumber:  63
inside squadNumber:  72
inside squadNumber:  81
inside squadNumber:  90

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(generate_number([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15, 18, 23, 69], 18), 99)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 16, in generate_number
    squadNumber = int(str(firstDigit)+str(secondDigit))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10-1'
```

So the following test would fail:

```
Test.it("should return next lowest, two-digit combination, if n is already taken")

Test.assert_equals(generate_number([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 11, 15, 18, 23, 69], 18), 99)
```

We have thought the direct approach: loop from 11 to 99 and return the lowest one which digits sum n:

```
def generate_number(squad, n):
    print("squad: ",squad)
    print("n: ",n)
    if n not in squad: return n
    for twoDigitsNumber in list(range(11,100)):
        if "0" in str(twoDigitsNumber): continue
        print("twoDigitsNumber: ",twoDigitsNumber)
        firstDigit=int(str(twoDigitsNumber)[0])
        secondDigit=int(str(twoDigitsNumber)[1])
        summed=firstDigit+secondDigit
        print("summed: ",summed)
        if twoDigitsNumber not in squad and summed==n: return twoDigitsNumber
    return None
```

We have read:

- [for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python)
- [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 0):

Your computation is faulty.  Look at your trace:

```
n:  18
squadNumber:  9
inside squadNumber:  9
inside squadNumber:  27
```

You fail to find `99`, because you've decided to replace the desired squad number with the sum of its digits; this is contrary to the specs.  You are supposed to search for a sum of 18, not 9.  Remove that replacement from your code, and it should work fine.