# Is there a way to create a list of characters, ord() them to integers, and hex() them to a hex code?

Tags: python, encryption, ord

I am a beginner programmer using Python, and I am trying to create encryption software (Beginner).
I am looking for something like:

Input: Apple  ->  A, P, P, L, E  -> ord() -> 97,"","","",""  -> hex()  -> 0x16, "","" ,"" ,""

However, I cannot find a way to translate my characters to integers while accounting for an unknown amount of characters in input.

```
Sentence = list(input("Enter"))
print(Sentence)
ord_sentence = []
for each in range(len(Sentence)):
    ord_sentence.append(ord(Sentence[]))
```

This then doesn't work because the argument at the end of Sentence is empty, but I don't know how to make it fill with each individual character. I could try

```
...
...
while len(ord_sentence) <= len(Sentence)
   ord_sentence.append(ord(sentence[0]))
   ord_sentence.append(ord(sentence[1]))
##Continues on to 1000 to account for unknown input##
```

But then, I run into INDEX ERROR when the input isn't exactly 1000 characters long, and putting something like:

```
...
ord_sentence.append(ord(sentence[0]))
if IndexError:
    print(ord_sentence)
    break
```

Only results in it printing the first digit of the sequence, and then breaking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!!

Comment: Try: `for each in Sentence: ord_sentence.append(ord(each))`.  This way  you are looping over characters in the sentence (i.e. each now is a character).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to read about how loops work again. When you iterate over something, the value gets assigned to a variable. In your code, that's `each`. You never use that variable for anything, but I think it's what you're looking for.

```
for each in range(len(Sentence)):
    ord_sentence.append(ord(Sentence[each]))
```

Iterating over a `range` and indexing as you're doing here works, but it's not as direct as just iterating on the list directly. You could instead do:

```
for each in Sentence:                   # no range, len, each is a character
    ord_sentence.append(ord(each))      # take its ord() directly
```

Or you could use a list comprehension to build a new list form an old one directly, without a separate loop and a bunch of `append` calls:

```
ord_sentence = [ord(each) for each in Sentence]
```

While `each` is the name you've been using in your code, it is better practice to give a more specific name to your variables, that tells you what the value means. In the first version here, where you're iterating over a `range`, I'd use `index`, since that's what the number you get is (an index into the list). For the other two, `value` or `character` might make more sense, since the value is a single character from the `Sentence` list. Speacking of that list, its name is a little misleading, as I'd expect a sentence to be a string, or maybe a list of words, not a list of characters (that might have come from more or less than one sentence, e.g. `['f', 'o', 'o']` or `['F', 'o', 'o', '.', ' ', 'B', 'a', 'r', '.']`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `while` loop for this. If possible, you should avoid using indexes — these are a frequent source of small bugs and can make the code hard to read. Python makes it very easy to loop directly over values. You should have a *really* good reason to use:

```
for each in range(len(Sentence)):
```

instead of:

```
for a_char in Sentence:
  # use a_char here
```

which will give you each character in turn

Or a comprehension, which will do the same and create a list at the same time. These are central to python.

```
[a_char for a_char in s]
```

Together with join and your `hex()` and `ord()` functions, this becomes very succinct. You can compose function like `hex(ord('A'))`. With that, you can make a comprehension that will handle strings of what ever length you pass:

```
s = "APPLE"

codedList = [hex(ord(c)) for c in s]
# ['0x41', '0x50', '0x50', '0x4c', '0x45']

# ... or:
codedstring = "".join(hex(ord(c)) for c in s)
# '0x410x500x500x4c0x45'
```

Answer (score 0):

this does what you asked for

```
s='APPLE';
l=list(s);
h=list(map(lambda x: '0x%x' % (ord(x)), l));
print(h);
```