# How can I write same code using python range()?

Tags: python-3.x

#In C/C++, I can have the following loop#
`for(int j = i * i; j <= N ;j += i)`
#How do the same thing in Python?#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might work:

```
from itertools import count

N = 11**2
i = 2
for j in count(start=i**2, step=i):
    if j**2 > N:
        break
    print(j)
```

[`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20count#itertools.count) starts at `i**2` this way and counts up in steps of `i`. then i use the `break` statement to break the loop if the condition `j**2 > N` is met.