# Python index initializing in "for" loop

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

In C++ or Java we can define indexes in loop like :

```
for(int i = 5 <---; i < array.size(); i++)
     for(j = i + 1 <---....)
```

I am newbie in Python and  can we impelement the same as above in python?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Take a look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(5, len(array)):
   for j in range(i+1, ...):
       rest of code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(5, len(array)):
    for j in range(i + 1, ...)):
        ...
```