# Need help from a EXPERT in Python Language, How can I repeat my python code 10 times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python, and I am learning web automation.
Let's say I am using pyautogui as pg

```
import pyautogui as pg
pg.moveTo(100, 150, 1)  # loop should start again from this line 2
pg.click(170, 670, 1)
pg.moveTo(460, 790, 1)
pg.doubleClick(172, 140, 1)
pg.moveTo(450, 100, 1)
pg.click(940, 350, 1)'''
```

Now I want to repeat this block of code 10 times, how can I achieve that?
Without using my interaction with computer? I don't want to copy and paste this code 10 more times.
I want this to stop automatically, when it's complete looping 10 times, without taking too much extra lines.

Comment: Try [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) for code block.

Comment: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @moin205's answer worked, it's not Pythonic. A more Pythonic answer would be to put it in a `for` loop, like so:

```
for i in range(10):
    new_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving your code block to a function, and run that function through a while loop, e.g.

```
def new_function():
   pg.moveTo(100, 150, 1)  # loop should start again from this line 2
   pg.click(170, 670, 1)
   pg.moveTo(460, 790, 1)
   pg.doubleClick(172, 140, 1)
   pg.moveTo(450, 100, 1)
   pg.click(940, 350, 1)

i = 0 
while i < 10: 
   new_function() 
   i += 1
```