# How to convert percentage to decimal when it is in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, decimal, percentage

```
rstocks = ['5.57%','3.95%','5.26%','5.49%','-1,80%']

stocks =[]
for i in rstocks:
     stock = rstocks[i]//100
     stocks.append(stock)
```

It keeps showing

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: When you use a `for` loop in python like `for i in rstocks:`, `i` will be the object in your `list`. `'5.57%'`, `'3.95%'`, etc.. So you would need to `stock = i // 100`. However the data type of your `list` elements is `str`.. So you won't be able to do math on them without converting anyway.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have two several errors in your code.

- You may be mistakenly put the value `-1,80%` instead of `-1.80%`.
- All the elements of your list are strings and strings have no integer
  division

To get integer division of your element of the list, first, you need to convert the element into integer then use operator. Look at my code below. I convert all the elements into `float` then multiplied it to `100`.

```
rstocks = ['5.57%', '3.95%', '5.26%', '5.49%', '-1.80%']

stocks = []
for x in rstocks:
    stocks.append(float(x.strip('%'))*100)
print(stocks)

Output
[557.0, 395.0, 526.0, 549.0, -180.0]
```

Further you need to get integer value then you can typecast `float` to `int`.

```
int(float(x.strip('%'))*100)
```

Or typecast later all the elements of stocks.

```
print([int(s) for s in stocks])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the value at last index on 'rstocks' is '-1.80%' instead of '-1,80%'. You can get a substring of the values in the loop and change the data type to float.

```
rstocks = ['5.57%','3.95%','5.26%','5.49%','-1.80%']
stocks =[]
for i in rstocks:
   stock = float(i[:-1])
   stocks.append(stock)
```