# How to filter some urls from python list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, python-re, urllib3

I wrote this code for extract images urls from a web page as I given. And it shows all images urls. But I need to filter "https://images.unsplash.com/profile" urls and print them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url= "https://unsplash.com/t/nature"

html_page= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(html_page)
images= []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    images.append(img.get('src'))

print(images)
```

I tried;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url= "https://unsplash.com/t/nature"

html_page= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(html_page)
images= []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    images.append(img.get('src'))

if "https://images.unsplash.com/profile" in images:
    print(images)
```

And didn't worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the `images` and then look if each of the `image` within `images` contains the required string or not.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

url= "https://unsplash.com/t/nature"

html_page= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(html_page)
images=[]
for img in soup. find_all('img'):
    images.append(img.get('src'))

for image in images:
    if "https://images.unsplash.com/profile" in image:
        print(image)
```

output -

```
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1544707963613-16baf868f301?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1604758536753-68fd6f23aaf7image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=16&h=16&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1516997253075-2a25da8007e7?auto=format&fit=crop&w=16&h=16&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1628142977790-d9f66dcbc498image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=16&h=16&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1593541755358-41ff2a4e41efimage?auto=format&fit=crop&w=16&h=16&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1635425197470-04119ef8fe14image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=16&h=16&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1578469980049-1a3edf161dd6image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1634467404821-bfebba1c1fa0image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1604529169445-f6fb0ce4419bimage?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1557995124272-d62d831ec026?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1629238389240-a728c73e5f2e?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1557995124272-d62d831ec026?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1639922696359-2aa9a8957e24image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1604529169445-f6fb0ce4419bimage?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1638495379168-a1d47187bac3?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1618382084065-fc61a6f289a5image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1604529169445-f6fb0ce4419bimage?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1638257899437-e27df4493c8a?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1613909172589-d6917d507f51image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1643893364520-052a85760bbeimage?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1613830526692-e8a5006d9b70image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1620741299521-03deb22f2a20image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1557995124272-d62d831ec026?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1641356925987-40e732340cc4?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1641356925987-40e732340cc4?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1582127823399-8b7c96db846eimage?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff
```

Comment: it worked. Thank you! Please can you explain how 'for image in images:' works?

Comment: It is python syntax for iterating through a `list`. e.g. `images` above is a `list` containing 91 image URLs but we printed only the above ones. Check out first part of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4171389/10522970, and running it to see how we iterate through list.  Please consider [accepting/upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it helped you.

Comment: **Note** In new code please use `find_all()` instead of `findAll()` that is an old syntax, still working, but should not be used.

Comment: Thanks for the node @HedgeHog, updated. I just used the original code snippet in the code and updated last few lines

Answer (score 2):

You can make your selection more specific with `css selectors`:

```
soup.select('img[src*="https://images.unsplash.com/profile"]')
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url= "https://unsplash.com/t/nature"
html_page= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup= BeautifulSoup(html_page)

images = [img['src'] for img in soup.select('img[src*="https://images.unsplash.com/profile"]')]

print(images)
```

#### Output

```
['https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1544707963613-16baf868f301?auto=format&fit=crop&w=32&h=32&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff', 'https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1604758536753-68fd6f23aaf7image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=16&h=16&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff', 'https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1516997253075-2a25da8007e7?auto=format&fit=crop&w=16&h=16&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff', 'https://images.unsplash.com/profile-1628142977790-d9f66dcbc498image?auto=format&fit=crop&w=16&h=16&q=60&crop=faces&bg=fff']
```

---

### EDIT

Just printing the urls line by line:

```
for img in soup.select('img[src*="https://images.unsplash.com/profile"]'):
    print(img['src'])
```

Comment: It worked, But I needed to print urls line by line. Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Added an EDIT based on your comment - Just print while iterating over your result set.

Comment: For big html this will be be much more optimal compared to my solution.