# How do you increment list string elements in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, increment

How can I increment these list string elements in a for loop?

```
mylist = ['and1', 'hello', 'world']

#some for loop
for i in np.linspace(start,stop,num_samples)
   print('This is %s' % mylist[0])
```

This gives output:

```
This is and1
This is and1
This is and1
```

My desired output is:

```
This is and1
This is hello
This is world
```

Is there an easy way to do this in python?

Comment: What is `np.linspace(start,stop,num_samples)` and why are you using it?

Comment: `for word in mylist: print(f"This is {word}")` ?

Comment: Hint: In `mylist[0]` the 0 can be replaced by a variable (or an expression).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [for loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170656/for-loop-in-python)

Comment: Your loop always prints `mylist[0]`, which is the first item.

Answer (score 2):

`mylist[0]` always refers to the initial index in the list, while you probably meant `mylist[i]`

However, you can directly iterate over lists

```py
for value in mylist:
    print(f"This is {value}")
```